# Выдает ошибку в строке mass[i] = random.nextInt(bound:30); Не могу понять что не так вроде всё правильно написано

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.random;

public class Random {
    

    public  static void random(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputFromCommandLine = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int masslenght = inputFromCommandLine.nextInt();
        int [] mass = new int[masslenght];
        Random random = new Random();
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length;i++) {
            mass[i] = random.nextInt(bound:30); 
        } 
        
        int number = inputFromCommandLine.nextInt();
        
        for (int element : mass) {
            if (element == number) {
                System.out.println(element);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: bound:30  - невалидная конструкция

Comment: что пишет ошибка? почему не прочитал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [докам](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) описание метода такое:

```
public int nextInt(int bound)
```

где `bound` - наименование параметра метода. А на вход он ожидает исключительно целое число

---

`bound:30` - невалидная конструкция. Желание так написать у вас одно: увидели на ютубе видео, где у человека так написано. Но на самом деле это не так, у него всего лишь *IDE*, которая подсвечивает, что нужно вставить текущее наименование параметра и что оно равно "30"

Comment: Я изначально не писал bound была ошибка, потом увидел на ютубчике такой пример и всё равно ошибка. Ошибка "Multiple markers at this line
 - The method nextInt(int) is undefined for the type Random"

Comment: @UkoledSid а вот не надо называть свой класс точно так же, как класс Java ;-)  Либо переименуйте свой класс и файл, либо придётся для random дописывать вручную неймспейс `java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();`

Comment: Спасибо большое  ))